# Formatting milliseconds to dd:hh:mm:ss in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Well, I'm trying to format millisecond to dd:hh:mm:ss. I have f.e. 206000 milliseconds.

This should be formatted like this: 00:00:03:26.

But if I use this code:

```
showTimeWithHour(milliSeconds: number): string {
    const date = new Date(milliSeconds);
    return formatDate(date, 'dd:hh:mm:ss', 'en-US')
}
```

I get  this result: 01:01:03:26 but it should be this 00:00:03:26.

Comment: @Dexygen Angular has a built in function called `formatDate`, which is used in this question. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angular-10-formatdate-method/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work:

```js
const timeWithMs = () => 
  `${new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB').split(' ')[1]}:${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`;

console.log(timeWithMs());
```

Basically i'm taking the current time and adding the current milliseconds to it.

if you want the milliseconds to be formatted into only 2 numbers, you could do the following:

```js
const timeWithMs = () => 
  `${new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB').split(' ')[1]}:${new Date().getMilliseconds().toString().slice(0,2)}`;

console.log(timeWithMs());
```

And you can also get the date as a parameter of the function:

```js
const timeWithMs = (date) => 
  `${date.toLocaleString('en-GB').split(' ')[1]}:${date.getMilliseconds().toString().slice(0,2)}`;

const someDate = new Date(12487125);
console.log(timeWithMs(someDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```js
function showTimeWithHour(milliSeconds) {
  days = Math.floor(milliSeconds / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  daysFromMilliSeconds = milliSeconds % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  hours = Math.floor((daysFromMilliSeconds) / (60 * 60 * 1000));
  hoursFromMilliSeconds = milliSeconds % (60 * 60 * 1000);
  minutes = Math.floor((hoursFromMilliSeconds) / (60 * 1000));
  minutesFromMilliSeconds = milliSeconds % (60 * 1000);
  seconds = Math.floor((minutesFromMilliSeconds) / (1000));

  days = days.toString().length == 1 ? days.toString().padStart(2, '0') : days.toString();
  hours = hours.toString().length == 1 ? hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') : hours.toString();
  minutes = minutes.toString().length == 1 ? minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') : minutes.toString();
  seconds = seconds.toString().length == 1 ? seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0') : seconds.toString();

  return days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

console.log(showTimeWithHour(206000));
```

Comment: With your solution only hh:mm:ss is displayed

Comment: Now I only get this format d:h:m:s f.e. 0:0:3:26

Comment: @govit19 I've updated my answer.